# How to save content from yii widget to Database?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

here is the ListBuilder Widget code:

```
$this->widget('ext.widgets.multiselects.XMultiSelects',array(
'leftTitle'=>'Australia',
'leftName'=>'Person[australia][]',
'leftList'=>Person::model()->findUsersByCountry(14),
'rightTitle'=>'New Zealand',
'rightName'=>'Person[newzealand][]',
'rightList'=>Person::model()->findUsersByCountry(158),
'size'=>20,
'width'=>'200px',
));
```

List Builder view [this](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/extension?view=listbuilder)

I wanna save that entire list i select to right list on to my DB.
how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is available so you just have to look in the controller:

```
public function actionMovePersons()
{
   if(isset($_POST['Person']['australia']))
   {
      foreach ($_POST['Person']['australia'] as $id)
      Person::model()->updateUserCountry($id, 14);
   }

   if(isset($_POST['Person']['newzealand']))
   {
      foreach ($_POST['Person']['newzealand'] as $id)
      Person::model()->updateUserCountry($id, 158);
   }
   Yii::app()->user->setFlash('saved',Yii::t('ui','Data successfully saved!'));
   $this->redirect(array('site/extension','view'=>'listbuilder'));
}
```

And in the model:

```
public function updateUserCountry($id, $country_id)
{
   $model=$this->findByPk($id);
   $model->country_id=$country_id;
   $model->update('country_id');
}
```

The above updates the Person in the database and sets the new country. If I understand your question correct you want to create new entries (maybe in a different table) instead of changing existing ones. To do this you can easily modify the `updateUserCountry()` function to create a new `Person` instead of updating it.

Comment: Thanks...

But, where am i triggering "Moveperson" action in my widget?

Comment: @satya The surrounding `form` defines which action is called.